# Access a website folder from another website in the same IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, c#-4.0

I have 4 independent ASP websites deployed in IIS server.

I access my website images using relativePath so i have root/path_to_files (something like that).

**My problem** is i want to access website1 images folder from website2 and so on, web3 access web4 (you get the picture).

I tried absolutePAth but security reasons (not safe) blocked me.

I`m reading the name and path of the repositories from a file.

What can I do, without remaking all or create a central repository(and upload all files there).

EDIT 1: using url is locked but i can unlock.
I can use url to get/list folders and images and use them ? Like resolve a url in a relativePATH to other website?!

**Central repository** the site is allready in production it will have big impact time/benfit to do that.

Comment: I would say you should do what you say you do not want to do. Create a site to serve static resources, CDN style.

Comment: What happens if you use the fully qualified path for the images? `http://example.com/img.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered symbolic links? You can make a shared image folder. Then each folder can see that "image" folder as its own.

Comment: On IIS it's called a virtual folder.

Comment: Virtual folders/symb links/hard links don`t work, when you access like xpto\Vpath you get the absolute path of the linked folder. I think i will go for CDN style

Comment: If you use IIS to join the folders sure.... Do it at the OS level not in IIS and it wont know the difference. I have used this successfully to share folders between web aps that both needed to server the same xls documents to its clients.